# Blackberry older simulator

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

my client wants me to make an application which works on pre4.0 os... i understand that if i make 1 like that then it wont work on the latest os...

But my actual problem is that though i did the coding correctly coz the application was just a simple WebIcon... i cant load it onto the 7290 simulator...

i tried javaloader -u load MyApp.jad and javaloader -u load MyApp.cod... but i get the following error

```
Error: unable to open port...
```

earlier it couldnt find javac... so i placed javac in the System32 folder... now the below shown error is displayed and further the simulator doesnt connect with even the 4.0 IDE....
even tried compiling in the 4.0 IDE itself... but i get the following error...

```
Error!: Error: java compiler failed: javac -source 1.3 -target 1.1 -g -O -d MyDir
```

Don know wat to do... plz help...

screenshot of the simulator...

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d9e1840ce0.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d9e1840ce0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well friends at last i tried uploading the applications .cod and .jad along with the optional .jar onto my company's server... and guess wat... it did download using the jar file but after trying all the techniques mentioned here... i guessed this was it...

But the application though gets listed in the applications but doesnt show up on the menu... and neither does it run in anyway...

Hence im closing with the research here... thanx a lot guys...

Answer (score 0):

I load my programs doing the following:

(Note: This is on an Curve 8310--which has a memory card slot--not sure if you can plug in the phone and use it in HardDisk mode)

- Plug the phone into the computer to enable HD mode
- Copy the .jad, .jar and .cod to the memory card (or device memory in your case if HD mode works for this) of the phone
- Click the Media Icon
- Open the menu within media and hit explore (Here I have an option for memory card OR device memory) -- Select the device memory
- Finally, find and select the .jad file -- the phone will ask if you want to download--just hit yes, and this will prompt for the install

Again, I realize this is a different (older) phone which you are using, so this method may not work.

Hope it helps!

Greg

Comment: thanx dude for the tip... but i spose they didnt provide the Memory card slot in older phones... hence this way also not working
secondly i tried to do the same with the desktop manager... but though it shows the connection with the simulator but doesnt let me load any program... clicking javaloader itself results in error! :( don know wat to do...